# What are the differences between normal polymorphism and the one using generic?

Tags: java, performance, oop, polymorphism

There is an abstract class BaseA here.

```
//class definition
public abstract class BaseA {
    void doSomething();
}
```

And there are two clients using the class BaseA as follows.

```
//the client A 
class clientA {
    void clientA(BaseA obj){
        obj.doSomething();
    }
    ...

//the client B  
class clientB<T extends BaseA> {
    void methodB(T obj){
        obj.doSomething();

    }
    ...
```

The question is there any difference between the two?
Which one is better, and why? Please advise.
*The question is not limited to the performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java generic Interface performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745944/java-generic-interface-performance)

Comment: Thank you for the page. Partially yes, but I need more info.

Comment: What more information?

Comment: I would like to know in which case, which one should I use.

Comment: Where is `Base` class?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it is updated.

Comment: They're not completely equivalent. The first one allows any type of `BaseA` whereas the second limits the type to `T`. If it doesn't make sense to declare a more specific type than `BaseA` and limit users of the API to said type, then don't use the second option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `ClientA` and `ClientB` is that `ClientB` is not only bound by `BaseA` but also `T`. As `T` cannot reduce the scope of any methods in `BaseA` the interface is identical.

According to the docs the [advantages of generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) are:

> - Stronger type checks
> - Elimination of casts
> - Enabling generic algorithms

When the usage of generics is limited like shown in the question there is little benefit in this regard. Stronger type checks applies here though.

The main difference is that `T extends BaseA` enforces a parameter to be exactly of type `T`. If the class used just `BaseA` any sub class of `BaseA` could be passed into the method.

**Example:**

```
class SubA extends BaseA {}
class SubB extends BaseA {}

class ClientA {
    void method(BaseA obj) {
        obj.doSomething();
    }
}
class ClientB<T extends BaseA> {
    void method(T obj) {
        obj.doSomething();
    }
}

ClientA a = new ClientA();
a.method(new SubA());
a.method(new SubB());

ClientB<SubA> b = new ClientB<>();
b.method(new SubA());
b.method(new SubB()); // fails
```

While `ClientA` allows for any `BaseA` being passed, `ClientB` allows for limiting it's usage to a specific sub type.